# Make api call if value from mongoDB is null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am developing an app and I am using MEAN stack. I have values saved in a database using MongoDB. I want to use those values to make API calls but only if a value is null. Now it is successfully getting those values from the database and making the calls to the API but I don't know how to check if the value is null, I have tried basically everything but I think I don't understand completely NodeJS and that it is asynchronous. This is the code that works but doesn't check if the value is null:

```
var makeApiCalls = function (workerId) {
    var Model = mongoose.model('Tweet'.concat(workerId), Tweet.tweetSchema);
    return Model.find({},{ _id: 1, message: 1}).then(messages =>
        Promise.all(
            messages.map(({ _id, message }) =>
                api.sentiment(message).then(result =>
                    Model.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, { resultOfTheCall: result }, { new: true })
                        .then( updated => { console.log(updated); return updated })
                )
            )
        )
    )
};
```

The mongoose model has a field called resultOfTheCall and I need to check if that value is null and only in that case, I want to make a call to the API with the field message.

This is the console.log of one of the message:

```
{ 
  _id: 5b85c83b413a2b1473e7122a,
  date: 'Tue Aug 28 22:10:02 +0000 2018',
  message: 'la gente quiere y no viene',
  resultOfTheCall: 0.5931016939587707,
  __v: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply filter the messages before making the `Promise.all`.

```
var makeApiCalls = function(workerId) {
  var Model = mongoose.model('Tweet'.concat(workerId), Tweet.tweetSchema);
  return Model.find({}, {
    _id: 1,
    message: 1,
    resultOfTheCall: 1
  }).then(messages => {
    // filter the mssages here those for which to make the call and the others
    var toCallArray = messages.filter(x => x.resultOfTheCall == null)
    var noCallArray = messages.filter(x => x.resultOfTheCall != null)
    // now do the calls for only those which do not have resultOfTheCall
    return Promise.all(
      toCallArray.map(({_id, message}) =>
        api.sentiment(message).then(result =>
          Model.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id
          }, {
            resultOfTheCall: result
          }, {
            new: true
          })
          .then(updated => {
            console.log(updated);
            return [...noCallArray, ...toCallArray]
          })
        )
      )
    )
  })
};
```

Comment: it is not working...I have tested it with a document that has resultOfTheCall not null and it keeps making the call.

Comment: I have added the console.log of one of the messages updated

Comment: it is still not working and the number of messages doesn't change before and after

Comment: the problem with your answer is that the filter doesn't know anything about the resultOfTheCall because in the find it's not specified. I have edited the find in your answer and maybe that will help you. But I am not entirely sure

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Yeah sure makes sense ... you ware projecting the fields above ...

Comment: The problem is that I need to return all the messages, not only the updated, how can I do that?

Comment: look at the return on the end ... you return `[...noCallArray, ...updated]` an array which contains the updated and the ones you filtered above to not make the API call for.

Comment: it is giving me this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: updated is not iterable

Comment: Updated was the count of updated records that is why the error. See if the above updated answer works for you.

Comment: it doesn't work but don't worry because in the question I didn't ask for that. You answer correctly what I was asking first. Thanks :)